# Customisation of AVPlayerViewController default controlsView

Tags: objective-c, tvos

Is there any way to customise the background and text colour of AVPlayerViewController default controls view?.

Answer (score 2):

Those attributes of AVPlayerViewController are, at least so far (tvOS 12), not customizable.

The only way to get a custom OSD layout is to completely disable the native solution making use of the property [playbackControlsIncludeTransportBar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/2874218-playbackcontrolsincludetransport), and implementing a whole custom slider.